# conversation.Impersonate returns SIP code 400

Tags: c#, sip, ucma

I'm using the following snippet of code and keep getting a 400 code from the SBC. I am using UCMA 4.0 to do this

```
conversation.Impersonate("sip:helpdesk@xyz.com", "tel:+2341234678", "Help Desk");
```

I've figured it out. It did not like being given the sip and a phone number at the same time. Giving it only the phone number fixed the 400.

Comment: I'm surprised that the impersonation is causing the Bad Request.  Could you post your code from the point that you create the conversation to the point you hit call.EndEstablish() please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the SIP uri fixed the problem.